# Filling out multi page web forms

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I can make the code below to work for multipage form, but it would be messy.  Basically, the biggest challenge is once I press the submit button, it loads a new page, and the WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler is called again, but with the same code.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebBrowser.Navigate(@"A_WEBSITE_URL");
        WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Null);
    }

    public void Null(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("UserId").SetAttribute("value", "MY_USER_NAME");
        WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("loginButton").InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved this by adding a counter that is ++ed each time the DocumentCompleted event is called.  Based on the value of counter, I have my code do whatever.